# glossaries with tikzDevice

Tags: glossaries, r, tikzdevice

I am using tikzDevice to run my R-scripts within latex.

This is my code --

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tikz} 


\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}


    Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
    its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
    process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.


    \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \input{rtikzFile}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where rtikzFile is created using R as follows --

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("rtikzFile.tex" )
options( tikzLatexPackages = c( getOption( "tikzLatexPackages" ), "\\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}"))
plot(1,1,xlab="XXX")
dev.off()
```

Now, I would like to use **`\gls{lcm}`** instead of **XXX** as x-label. I have tried using `\\gls\\{lcm\\}` and also `\\gls{lcm}`. Everything just return errors, something like --

> File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2013/12/13  (rss-revision 1.23) \Error
>   in getMetricsFromLatex(TeXMetrics, verbose = verbose) :  TeX was
>   unable to calculate metrics for the following string or character:
>
> \gls{lcm}

**Edit after comments -**

Problem is (Guess) : - I need to pass `\makeglossaries` and also the compiled glossary files to it. I don't know how to do it.

Alternatively, I can just use `\gls{lcm}` in the **rtikzFile.tex** file generated after executing with `R`. But this is not an automated way.

Comment: same question on another platform, see the actual problem here -- https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice/issues/144#issuecomment-227581146

Comment: Where can `tiki.sty` be found?

Comment: A typo... It is tikz.

Comment: I've never use R or tikzdevice, but I'm guessing if you have to supply `"\\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}"` then you'll also need to supply the entry definitions.

Comment: exactly, that's the problem. I must pass compiled glossary to it. I will edit the post now.

Comment: This is pure guesswork, but have you tried creating a file called, say, `gloss.tex` and put `\makeglossaries` and all your `\newacronym` commands in it. Then change `"\\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}"` to `"\\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}\\input{gloss}"` in your `rtikzFile.tex`.

Comment: yes, I agree. First of all, I was not sure if I can pass something like `\\input{...}`. Now I tried to pass `\\input{gloss}` and also `\\input{main.acn}`. Nothing helps. Now, I have a second thought, tikzDevice is transferring the R code to Latex tikz script then do I really need these compiled file?